# Truncation and merging values in two character vectors

Tags: r, vector, sapply, mapply

I have a character vector `V1`

```
V1 <- c("377 Peninsula St. Ogden,UT","8532 West Lyme St. Chesterfield, 
VA","43 E. Hilltop Street Hilliard,OH","95 Newcastle St. 
Hendersonville,NC","7276 Rose St. Greenville,NC")
```

and another vector as `V2`

```
V2 <- c(84404,23832,43026,28792,27834)
```

Now I have these conditions:

1) Break each item in `V1` at `24th` character:

---

a) If 24th character is a `comma` then break the string there and remaining should be added to corresponding string in V2.
e.g. `V1` has "`377 Peninsula St. Ogden, UT`", wherein we have comma at 24th index thus we need to break this in two "`377 Peninsula St. Ogden`" "`UT`" (mind that comma itself is omitted) and then `V1` gets "`377 Peninsula St. Ogden`" part and remaining is added to corresponding PIN in `V2` thus "`84404`" in `V2` becomes "`UT 84404`"

b) If 24th character is `non-comma` and `non-whitespace` find out last whitespace before comma in `V1` and upto that index `V1` keeps, remaining goes to `V2`.
e.g. `V1` has "`8532 West Lyme St. Chesterfield, VA`", wherein we have "`t`" at 24th index thus we need to break it from the whitespace after "`St.`" thus `V1` keeps "`8532 West Lyme St.`" and `V2` gets "`Chesterfield, VA 23832`".

---

By the end of the operations we should have:

```
V1 <- c("377 Peninsula St. Ogden","8532 West Lyme St.",...)
V2 <- c("UT 84404","Chesterfield, VA 23832")
```

EDIT:

I tried following function on V1 to know whether 24th character is a comma:

```
unlist(lapply(lapply(V1, function(z){substr(z,24,24)}),function(y){y==","}))
```

which returns:

> TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

Now that I have solved one part of the problem, I need a way to apply the formatting logic based on the result above.

i.e. I want to do:

```
unlist(lapply(lapply(V1, function(z){substr(z,24,24)}),function(y){if(y==","){something1} else if(y==" "){something2}else {something3}}))
```

Here something1/2/3 come from 1a and 1b above.
Need to know how to write this logic.

Comment: This appears to be a homework or classwork problem. Where is your attempt at solution? And what errors or undesired results occur?

Comment: Definitely not a homework, I tried following function on V1 to know whether 24th character is a comma: unlist(lapply(lapply(V1, function(z){substr(z,24,24)}),function(y){y==","})) which returns TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE, the problem i am facing is how to accommodate condition b in this and also how to manipulate the vectors based on the outcome of the above function.

Comment: unlist(lapply(lapply(V1, function(z){substr(z,24,24)}),function(y){if(y==","){something1} else if(y==" "){something2}else {something3}})) , I want to know how to  write these something to get the desired results. Hope the downvote can be removed now.

Comment: Please edit your post with code attempts (not in comments which are difficult to read) and describe or better show current and desired results.

Comment: Editted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following using vectorized methods of `ifelse`, `substr`, and `regexpr` (i.e., no apply loops):

```
newV1 <- ifelse(substr(V1, 24, 24) == ",",         # CONDITIONALLY CHECK 24TH CHARACTER
                substr(V1, 1, regexpr(",", V1)-1), # EXTRACT UNTIL 24TH CHARACTER
                substr(V1, 1, 
                       regexpr(" (?=[^ ]+$)", 
                               substr(V1, 1, 24), 
                               perl=TRUE)-1)     # EXTRACT UNTIL LAST SPACE BEFORE 24TH CHAR
                )
newV1
# [1] "377 Peninsula St. Ogden" "8532 West Lyme St."     
# [3] "43 E. Hilltop Street"    "95 Newcastle St."       
# [5] "7276 Rose St."        

newV2 <- paste(ifelse(substr(V1, 24, 24) == ",",   # CONDITIONALLY CHECK 24TH CHARACTER
               substr(V1, regexpr(",", V1)+1, 
                      nchar(V1)),                  # EXTRACT AFTER 24TH CHARACTER
               substr(V1, 
                      regexpr(" (?=[^ ]+$)", 
                              substr(V1, 1, 24), 
                              perl=TRUE)+1, 
                      nchar(V1))),               # EXTRACT AFTER LAST SPACE BEFORE 24TH CHAR
               V2)                               # PASTE V2 VECTOR ELEMENTWISE
newV2
# [1] "UT 84404"                "Chesterfield, VA 23832" 
# [3] "Hilliard,OH 43026"       "Hendersonville,NC 28792"
# [5] "Greenville,NC 27834"
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/MJM57367)